# SQL to compare records with and without given string is very slow, IS it possible to optimize?

Tags: mysql

I have this query.

```
    SELECT WithoutX.Field1, WithoutX.Field3 ,AVG(WithoutX.Field2) AS WO_X, AVG(withX.Field2) AS with_X 
FROM (
    SELECT ROUND(Table1.Field3,1) as Field3,Table3.Field2,Table2.Field1
    FROM Table1 
    INNER join Table2 
    ON Table1.Field5 = Table2.Field5 AND instr (Table2.Field1,'X')>0
    LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Field4 = Table1.Field4
    ) AS withX 
 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ROUND(Table1.Field3,1) as Field3,Table3.Field2,Table2.Field1
    FROM Table1 
    INNER join Table2 
    ON Table1.Field5 = Table2.Field5 AND instr (Table2.Field1,'X')=0
    LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Field4 = Table1.Field4
    ) AS WithoutX ON withX.Field3 = WithoutX.Field3 AND removeX(withX.Field1,'X') = WithoutX.Field1 
 GROUP BY WithoutX.Field1, WithoutX.Field3
```

removeX is a function that removes the substring x and other parts of the string in field1, so that the two derived tables WithoutX and WithX can be join based on field1.
It's working but it's very slow. I checked each parts separately and it seams the slowing down comes from the main INNER Join and the Group By. But the function does not change much the speed. Is there any way to optimize this query ?

Comment: Joining on a function is not sargable - this forces a scan of all rows, remove the need for the function by also storing its result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by storring it's results. I had the function in the first select that produce the withx subtable but it was not faster.

Comment: Can you make a view of the table viewed through the lens of this particular function, then materialize and properly index that view?

Comment: Before we fix your code, can you make sure it actually returns the correct result? The avg() on the outside look like you just put them in to make the group by work, but might not return the value you expect (e.g. it will in general not return the average for field2 on the table, but the average of a table joined with a table, which is the same only in very specific data distributions - which of course might be the case in your situation). If you are not sure, you may want to manually check some of the averages in your result (specifically cases where `LEFT JOIN Table3` has more than 1 match).

Comment: How fast is the WithX query by itself?  I'm thinking that a `UNION` would be better than a `JOIN` to of the two halfs.

Comment: The WithX function takes 0.014s, ( even with the removeX function in it).  WithoutX takes 0.0038s.  The whole query with the Left Join take over 200s ( and sometimes times out). 
The whole query with INNER join instead of LEFT join takes 4s
 This is for running the query with a little over over 7000 entries in table1, 5000 in table2 and 500 in table 3

Comment: tadman. Can you do what you say dynamically ? On my web search engine, the user can selct different fields of table3 to be fields2. So I can't create tables that will stay in the database

Comment: I inserted the results from the withoutx and withx derived tables into real tables. Then run the INNER join and group by on them and it takes 6 seconds